# How to change both charset (NLS_CHARACTERSET) and National Charset (NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET) to UTF8 on a RDS Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, utf-8, character-encoding, amazon-rds

Our application is designed to work with an Oracle 11g database with *Charset* (`NLS_CHARACTERSET`) and *National Charset* (`NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`) both set to UTF8.

While lauching an Oracle database instance on Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS), I'm prompted to chose a *Charset* that I set to UTF8.

However, I was unable to find a way to set the *National Charset*, and this parameter is set to `AL16UTF16` during database creation.

I tried the following :

- Created a new Parameter Group to set the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`, but the parameter isn't listed. I also tried unsuccessfully to force the creation of a new Parameter Group with this parameter using the AWS CLI.
- Tried to `ALTER` the database but the `SYSDBA` role is not available on Amazon managed database instances.
- Created different Oracle RDS databases with different *Charset* parameter to check if the *National Charset* is affected, but it is still set to `AL16UTF16`.

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter can be set by specifying --character-set-name during instance creation using AWS CLI. So far I have not found anyway to change that for an existing instance.

In my testing, I set it using --character-set-name KO16MSWIN949, which will support Korean based on AWS doc:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.OracleCharacterSets.html

Comment: Downvote. The answer does not ask the original poster's question, namely how to set the National Charset (NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET) to UTF8 in AWS RDS.

Answer (score 1):

## CLI option --nchar-character-set-name

Beginning with AWS cli version 2.0.55 of Oct 7, 2020, you can use:

```
aws rds create-db-instance --nchar-character-set-name UTF8
```

You may also use boto3 create_db_instance option NcharCharacterSetName.

Setting *national* character set (nchar) does *not* appear on the AWS console.

Answer (score -1):

Using Cloudformation you can set it too in the CharacterSetName attribute of AWS::RDS::DBInstance.

Comment: Downvote. The answer does not ask the original poster's question, namely how to set the National Charset (NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET) to UTF8 in AWS RDS.